In DFT codes, which energy is forces derivatives of?
There was a discussion in our research group recently, that I did not follow completely, but the crux was:

In most DFT codes (especially VASP), when we compute the forces, which energy are the forces derivatives of? Is it consistent across different DFT methods and codes?

Confusion stems mainly from when reported calculations have finite temperature energy, or free energy etc., as opposed to 0K.
Are the forces now derivative of the free energy, or still the 0K energy?

In ORCA and BDF it is the free energy. In other programs it's probably also the free energy, because the free energy's gradient is mathematically the simplest, but I'm not sure.

Thank you for the comment, do you mean free energy at 0 K? What if I ask it to compute finite temp energy? are forces always the -ve gradients of free energy in ORCA?

I mean the free energy at finite temperature. In general you cannot calculate the gradient at 0K from a SCF wavefunction at finite temperature (btw at 0K it doesn't matter whether it is the energy or free energy, since they are equal), unless you reconverge the wavefunction at 0K.

Are you talking about the forces on atoms during a frequency calculation (i.e., harmonic force field)? Because, if you are, as far as I am aware, it is only the electronic energy—temperature has no input in the calculation. Although @wzkchem5 can correct me if I'm wrong

@isolatedmatrix In many molecular codes, the keyword for temperature only changes the nuclear temperature, and therefore only changes the enthalpy, Gibbs free energies etc., but not the frequencies or forces themselves. But it is also possible to input an electronic temperature, which allows a small fraction of electrons to occupy virtual orbitals and therefore change the electronic structure. You then see changes of the forces and frequencies. However, for molecules with non-degenerate ground states, the effect of electronic temperature is frequently negligible. So few people talk about it

By contrast, periodic code users frequently want to calculate metallic systems, which have no band gap and therefore the electronic temperature has some real effect. Moreover, one usually has to use a non-zero electronic temperature to converge the SCF of metallic systems, even if the user is interested in the 0K behavior. This is what the OP is asking about. The "free energy" mentioned by the OP is not the free energy with nuclear contributions calculated by molecular codes, but the free energy with only electronic energy and electronic entropy contributions.

@wzkchem5 ahhhh, that makes sense! It never occurred to me that you could change the electronic temperature. I just assumed free energy was Gibbs energy, and that the forces/temperatures OP referred to were related to the thermal corrections. My mistake.

I haven't looked into this for a while, but IIRC the forces are the same because the derivative of the entropic term wrt atomic position is zero.
